# Is my "git svn" repository ahead of subversion repository?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

For normal git process, I can use 'git status' to get a similar message like:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Is there any git svn command could let me know what's require to dcommit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git branch -a` shows like

```
* master
  my_branch
  remote/git-svn
```

`git log git-svn..` show the commit log ahead of last svn check in log.

To get the count of commits which ahead of svn, just reference this [blog](https://joshdick.net/2012/12/30/my_git_prompt_for_zsh.html)

```
git log --oneline git-svn.. 2> /dev/null | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `git status` like without `git svn`.

You just have to set the svn-remote-tracking-branch as upstream branch and `git status` will give you the same information as for non `git svn` repo where it also just shows the difference against the configured upstream branch **if** one is configured.